# How to display a status depending on the data flow position

Tags: labview

Consider for example this modified Simple TCP sample program: 
[image]

How can I display the current state of the program like

1. Wait for Connection
2. Connected
3. Connection terminated

on the frontpanel, depending on where the "data flow" currently is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to place a **string indicator** on your front panel and write messages to a **local variable** of this indicator at each point where you want to see a status update.

You need to keep in mind how LabVIEW dataflow works: code will execute as soon as the data it depends on becomes available. Sometimes you can use existing structures to enforce this - for example, if you put a string constant inside your loop and wire it to a local variable terminal outside the loop, the write will only happen after the loop exits. Sometimes you may need to enforce that dataflow artificially, for example by placing your operation inside a **sequence frame** and connecting a wire to the border of the sequence: then what's inside the sequence will only happen after data arrives on that wire. (This is about the only thing you should use a sequence for!)

This method is not guaranteed to be deterministic, but it's usually good enough for giving a simple status indication to the user.

A better version of the above would be to send the status messages on a **queue** or **notifier** which you read, and update the status indicator, in a separate loop. The queue and notifier write functions have error terminals which can help you to enforce sequence. A notifier is like the local variable in that you will only see the most recent update; a queue keeps all the data you write to it in the right order so would be more suitable if you want to log all the updates to a scrolling list or log file. With this solution you could add more features: for example the read loop could add a timestamp in front of each message so you could see how recent it was.

A really good solution to this general problem is to use a design pattern based on a **state machine**. Now your program flow is clearly organised into different states and it's very easy to add in functionality like sending a different message from each state. There are good examples and project templates for these design patterns included with recent versions of LabVIEW.

You should be able to find more information on any of the terms in bold in the LabVIEW help or on the NI website.